# Установка yii2. Избавиться от frontend/web/ и backend/web/ в url-е

Tags: php, yii2

Устанавливаю yii2. Мне необходимо сделать так чтобы по ссылке
"site.ru/" - выдавалась стартовая страница, а по ссылке "site.ru/admin/" открывалась админская часть. Сейчас они доступны только по ссылкам "site.ru/backend/web/index.php" и "site.ru/frontend/web/".

ВОПРОС В СЛЕДУЮЩЕМ.

Я нашел множество вариантов как это сделать с помощью htaccess-ов(например здесь https://pro-cod.ru/ubiraem-frontend-web-i-backend-web-yii2.html). И с ними все работает. НО неужели в yii2 нет встроенных способов решений этой проблемы? Неужели нужно обязательно так "костылить"? Может можно просто в каком нибудь конфиге прописать эти урлы и все заработает? Или такого способа не предусмотрено?

Answer (score 0):

Файл `.htaccess` позволяет изменять настройки веб-сервера Apache для конкретного хоста. Yii2 не умеет редактировать эту конфигурацию и лишь обрабатывает поступающие запросы к конкретному скрипту.

Вы можете не создавать файл `.htaccess` и настроить конфигурацию напрямую в файле конфигурации виртуал хоста Apache, указав `DocumentRoot`:

````bsh
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/project/frontend/web"
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    ...
</VirtualHost>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Не надо городить все в кучу. `frontend` и `backend` это разные хосты. Обычно фронт открывается по запросу `site.ru`, а все остальные цепляют на поддомены (`admin.site.ru`). Для каждого хоста корневой директорией должна быть директория web. Для фронта `/project-path/frontend/web/`, например. Делается это для того, чтобы запросы из сети не могли добраться до файлов основного приложения. Такая вот своеобразная безопасность.

И когда у нас наравне с frontend и backend появляются еще экземпляры приложений (api, forum, payment...), то мы делаем для них отдельный хост и точно также корневой директорией является `/project-path/api/web/`.

Теперь представим, что у нас корневой директорией является директория всего проекта и все запросы отправляются туда.Возникает солидный набор костылей в файлах конфигурации хоста,
открывается потенциальная дыра (например, из `api` можно добраться до `payment` или другой директории).